# How do i test a view when its authentication resides on another service using DjangoREST

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework, mocking, microservices

I have two services, ServiceA and ServiceB. ServiceA is the authentication service and returns a JWT token after authenticating a user. ServiceB accesses data from the token using the `request.auth` object. Permissions are implemented on ServiceB, which also makes use of `request.auth` data to grant permissions which are written in my `permissions.py` file. But when testing a protected view, my views seem not to be able to pass through the permission class, as I keep getting an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`. I know that this error is because my test could not pass a `request.auth` object to the permissions file. I have tried mocking my `IsVerified`permission class to pass in my test file but still kept getting the error. Been working on this for a while and need to get my tests to pass. Below are some of my implementations.

*permissions.py*

```
class IsVerified(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            verified = cm.Company.objects.filter(contact_person=request.auth.get('email'), 
                                                 verified=True).exists()
            if verified:
                is_verified = True
            else:
                is_verified = False
        except cm.Company.DoesNotExist:
            is_verified = False
        return is_verified
```

*views.py*

```
class DepartmentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, cp.IsVerified])
    def get_company_members(self, request):
        try:
            organisation = request.auth.get('organisation')
            user = am.A.objects.filter(company_name__exact=organisation)
            serializer = aps.ASerializer(user, many=True)
        except am.AppUser.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': "User does not exist"}, 
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

tests.py

```
...
perm = cpm.IsVerified()
perm.has_permission = MagicMock(return_value=True)

# authenticated, contact person and verified
self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)
response = self.client.get(reverse("department-get-company-members"), {'company_name': 
                           'test_company_name2'})
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
self.client.force_authenticate(user=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would check.

1. Make sure you define the correct authentication class in
   DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES in your settings and make sure you have set the JWT auth class.
2. To access the user email, I use request.user.email
3. The way you usually authenticate users with JWT is via a http header. I don't know what jwt library you are using but it would look like this.

`self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {}'.format(token))`

Or

`self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='{} {}'.format(type, token))`

Where the token is generated using your JWT library.

`type` would refer to the type of token you want to use, for authentication, you need to use the access token.

Comment: This solution is under the premise that the Authentication is done in the same project. In my case, the authentication is done in another project entirely. As a service.

Comment: oh ok. But that doesn't change the fact that you second backend must be able to read the JWT token generated by the first backend. It must share the JWT encryption key to be able to associate the token to a user. There is no magic, the token must be transmitted to the second backend, in a header, http cookie or whatever pleases you. We don't really care where the token was generated...

Comment: My system works perfectly well, the two services communicate perfectly. the challenge is forcing authentication during TEST since the user model and the authentication module does not reside on ServiceB.

Comment: So it's really all about using force_authenticate. I think it only applies to user on the request object. So if you were able to change request.auth.get('email") to request.user.email, this could work.